# An application of Muirhead inequality

Tags: inequality

I'm having some difficulties with proving the following task using **Muirhead inequality**.

$$\cfrac{x_1}{x_2+x_3+...+x_n}+\cfrac{x_2}{x_1+x_3+...+x_n}+...+\cfrac{x_n}{x_1+x_2+...+x_{n-1}}\ge\cfrac{n}{n-1}$$

It looks like a generalized version of *Nesbitt's inequality*, however using Muirhead to prove classic Nesbitt seemed way easier. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Assuming that all numbers are positive and that the second inequality misses a factor $3$ in the denominator, both follow from convexity of $(1-x)^{-1}$ (in a proper domain) and Jensen’s inequality.

Comment: @WimC. Thanks for your feedback! All numbers are positive, right. The second inequality doesn't miss anything though. This is how I found it at least. Any ideas how Muirhead might help?

Comment: In the second inequality, if all numbers are $1$ then $\tfrac43 \geq 4$?

Comment: Ah, you are right. Clearly a mistake in the task. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's write  $\sum x_i =S$ and $A_j= S-x_j$
We need to prove

$\sum \frac{x_i}{A_i} \geq \frac{n}{n-1}$

$ \iff \sum \frac{S}{A_i} \geq \frac{n^2}{n-1}$

$\iff S(\sum \frac{1}{A_i}) \geq \frac{n^2}{n-1}$

$\iff S(\frac{n^2}{\sum A_i}) \geq \frac{n^2}{n-1}$ by AM-HM

$\iff S(\frac{n^2}{(n-1)S}) \geq \frac{n^2}{n-1}$.

Comment: I believe the goal is to prove via Muirhead.